# how do I check an array of tuples for a value in index[0] and if there is a match, display the value at index [1] of the matching tuple

Tags: javascript, typescript, tuples

I have an array of tuples:

```
var tuparray: [string, number][];
 tuparray = [["0x123", 11], ["0x456", 7], ["0x789", 6]];

const addressmatch = tuparray.includes(manualAddress);
```

I want my function to check if the tuparray contains a user input (string), manualAddress. If it finds a match in any of the tuples, it should display the value from the number at [1] of the tuple.

```
if (addressmatch){
console.log("address qualifies for [matched tuple number here]");
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `find()` on the `Array` and provide a lambda function to evaluate the match.

```js
var tuparray = [["0x123", 11], ["0x456", 7], ["0x789", 6]];

function includes(manualAddress) {
    const found = tuparray.find(x => x[0] == manualAddress)
    
    if (found) {
        console.log(`address qualifies for ${found[1]}`)
    } else {
        console.log(`Not found`)
    }
}

includes('0x123')
includes('0x456')
includes('0x111')
```

Comment: Really appreciate the insight . I had to modify things a little bit for my real life scenario but you got me 99% of the way there - note I found in my file to call the number value - I had to use the syntax (found[1]) but this worked beautifully.